# Delete Operation Slows down intermittently oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, delete-row

We have a audit Table in production environment where we delete almost 15 millions data everyday(data which is older than some days)in PL/SQL batch. On a good day this query takes 1.5 hours to delete the same data. But intermittently some days this is not deleting the same amount of data even in 4 hours. There is no trigger on this table and Created column is indexed.

```
DELETE FROM SIEBEL.CX_AUDIT_SEARCH
WHERE CREATED < '20-MAy-2020' AND rownum <= 10000;
```

Explain pla:

```
DELETE STATEMENT    ALL_ROWS    6   10000   180000                  
DELETE SIEBEL.CX_AUDIT_SEARCH                                   
COUNT(STOPKEY)                                  ROWNUM<=10000
INDEX(RANGE SCAN) SIEBEL.CX_AUDIT_SEARCH_U1 ANALYZED    6   170692  3072456             "CREATED"<'20-MAy-2020'
```

Could you please suggest any possible reason.

Comment: Well, you could (& should) use date instead of string in `where created < date '2020-05-20'`; why forcing Oracle to spend time on datatype conversion? Apart from that, who knows ... maybe database server suffers from something  (additional processing) during those "slow" days.

Comment: Without the real execution (DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR *not* EXPLAIN PLAN) or AWR/Statspack reports to compare database instance actiivity we can only guess: why guess when you can really know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s obvious that this is a very busy table. 15M rows/day means about 10416 rows/minute, which means that at the time you are deleting these rows, thousands of records are being inserted. While Oracle tries to delete the old rows, and update the CREATED index, more rows are inserted and committed.

I see you are trying to DELETE 10000 rows at a time. I assume you commit after these 10000 rows, so the following approach may be a bit faster because the SELECT is running only once and you don't rescan 1500 times the busy table...

```
declare 
cursor c_rowids is
  SELECT T.ROWID
      FROM SIEBEL.CX_AUDIT_SEARCH T
     WHERE CREATED < '20-MAy-2020';
type t_tbl_rowids is table of rowid;
tbl_rowids t_tbl_rowids;
begin
  open c_rowids;
  Loop
    fetch c_rowids bulk collect into tbl_rowids limit 10000;
    exit when tbl_rowids.count = 0;
    forall i in 1..tbl_rowids.count
      DELETE FROM SIEBEL.CX_AUDIT_SEARCH
        WHERE ROWID = tbl_rowids(i);

    COMMIT;
  End loop;
  close c_rowids;
end;
```

Comment: yes I know this bulk collect make operation faster and I know we have some other options as well like partitioning but I am more interested in the reason like why sometimes batch is not getting finished even in 4 hours??

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

For this process, you want to *partition* the table.  This stores the table in separate "files" for each partition.  And partitions can be dropped -- this process is much faster than deleting the rows.

You have described the rows to be deleted as rows older than a particular date.  That is the sweet spot for a partitioning solution.

You can learn more about it in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm).  I am surprised that you could have such a large database and not be aware of this functionality.

Comment: Every Oracle Database customer does not have Enterprise Edition EE : and even for those having it, some don't have the partitioning option which is still an "non-free" (extra-cost) option in EE: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dblic/Licensing-Information.html#GUID-AB56CEE3-955E-4E56-8B44-6075E889C283

Comment: @pifor . . . I would expect someone deleting 15 million rows *per day* to have the enterprise edition.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. But I do know customers who have EE without partitioning option.

Comment: @pifor . . . 15 million *deletes* per day, suggests at least 15 million inserts.  That, in turn, suggests about 174 inserts *per second* on average -- which is a lot even if these are bulk inserts.  The OP should really have a real database, real hardware, and real DBA for such a system.

Comment: Absolutely: and if the OP would have a "real' DBA he would not ask such questions on  public forums -:).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: But question here is why same batch with same amount data is taking longer to complete intermittently.

Comment: We are already working on partitioning solution but for customer point of view consider it. Its a valid question from customer that why partitioning, because same batch is getting completed in same 1.5 hours.

Comment: @alokkumar . . . You are doing something that can be accomplished in less than a minute, with the right approach.  Either timing seems way too long.

Comment: CTAS can not be done because during batch execution system is in Online mode. Other option is partitioning that we are working on. Other than this what other solution you have.